# Attempting to use service client factory with no configured API client

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to add isp(in skill purchase) to my Alexa Skill. The skill code is written in python and in the Launch request handler i have written the following code:

```
locale = handler_input.request_envelope.request.locale
monetization_service = handler_input.service_client_factory.get_monetization_service()
product_response = monetization_service.get_in_skill_products(locale)

if isinstance(product_response, InSkillProductsResponse):
   in_skill_product_list = product_response.in_skill_products
   self._logger.info(in_skill_product_list)
```

When I am running my lambda though I am getting the following error:

```
Attempting to use service client factory with no configured API client
```

Has anybody faced this issue let me know what is it am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

While initializing the skillbuilder i was using

```
sb = SkillBuilder()
```

This SkillBuilder does not have APIClient configured. Instead changing it to

```
sb = StandardSkillBuilder()
```

works as it has ApiClient configured.

Comment: The full answer for this is to use:
`from ask_sdk.standard import StandardSkillBuilder`
and then:
`sb = StandardSkillBuilder`
Examples often show the import as `from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder` which won't work here.